# Suppose that H is a subgroup of $S_p$ of order p show the following

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that H is a subgroup of $S_p$ of order p, then show that $N_G(H) / C_G(H) \simeq Aut(H)$. I showed that $N_G(H)$ is of order p(p - 1), but I have no idea what Aut(H) look like or $C_G(H)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the induced map $\varphi_x:h\mapsto xhx^{-1}$ for $x\in N_G(H)$. Is this map an automorphism of $H$?